# How to enable backspace on autocomplete field angular

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-material, angular1.6

I have some autocomplete fields in a form that doesn't clear the text when backspace key is pressed. I need to enable the backspace function but i dont know anything about angular js and I haven't find anything helpful online for this case.
Autocomplete is defined in a file that is called angular-material.js .Angular is version 1.6 .
Here is the html side of the field:

```
<md-autocomplete flex required ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
                    md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedProvince"
                    md-search-text="ctrl.searchTextProvince"
                    md-items="item in ctrl.queryProvince(ctrl.searchTextProvince)"
                    md-selected-item-change="ctrl.searchProvinceChange(item)"
                    md-item-text="item.province" md-min-length="0"
                    md-floating-label="Provincia"> <md-item-template>
                <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchTextProvince"
                    md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.province}}</span> </md-item-template> <md-not-found>
                No result containing "{{ctrl.searchText}}" &egrave; is found. <!--     <a ng-click="ctrl.newState(ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>-->
                </md-not-found> </md-autocomplete>
```

Anybody can help me on what should i modify to enable the backspace?(Delete key is working)

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I am facing same issue with angularjs 1.5.7 and angular material 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

' md-no-cache="true" ', This will help to enable backspace on autocomplete.